# Como deixar uma div e uma imagem por cima de um carousel?

Tags: css, css3, front-end

Quero fazer um carrousel e por cima dele, uma div e a logo, para dar aquele efeito de estar sobreposto.

Tente fazer como neste [EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/gtw7375/jdbzqyaL/), mas sem sucesso. Quando adiciono tais propriedades (`absolute e relative`) ao código do carousel o mesmo não funciona.

[image: O que desejo fazer]

As imagens de fundo em slide em forma de Carousel. A div verde e a logo sobreposta no carousel.

Tentei algo como:

```css
#myCarousel{
 position: absolute;
}

#fixa{
 position: absolute;
 width: 20%;
 height: 400px;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    
    <div id="fixa">
   DIV QUE SERÁ SOBREPOSTA
    </div>
    
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.savoir.com.br/cea.com.br/imagem/cadastrocqlv/imagem/cadastrocqlv-53440.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.asia-turismo.com/imagens/asia-imagem.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isso que queria:

```css
#fixa{
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(15, 215, 115, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    
    <div id="fixa">
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.savoir.com.br/cea.com.br/imagem/cadastrocqlv/imagem/cadastrocqlv-53440.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.asia-turismo.com/imagens/asia-imagem.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

À sua `div#fixa` atribui um `height: 100%`, e continuei com o `position: relative`, e usei o `z-index: 10`, como os outros elementos não tinha em suas especificações a propriedade `z-index`, o que tem será o que ficará acima de todos. Deve-se ter uma atenção para que a `div` não sobreponha os controladores.

A transparência foi com o `rgba(15, 215, 115, 0.5)`, em que o último parâmetro é a opacide que vai de 0 a 1. Isso poderia ser substituído por `rgb(15, 215, 115)` e um `opacity: 0.5`.

Comment: É exatamente isso, obrigado! Tinha esquecido completamente da propriedade `z-index` rsrs E se eu quiser colocar qualquer outra imagem e ou div por cima (Sendo mais específico, a LOGO), novamente basta navegar pelo `z-index`e pronto?

Comment: @Zkk. Sim, é basicamente isso. Lembrando que irá depender um pouco do `position`, mas no caso colocando um `absolute`, imagino que tudo correrá bem :)

Answer (score 1):

Para sobrepor arquivos utilize a propriedade css `z-index:9999` onde `9999` é o valor que voce deseja, quanto maior mais acima ele se posicionará.

Comment: Dando uma pesquisada, fiquei sabendo que colocar o `z-index:999` é uma má prática, pois esta não é uma forma consciente de posicionamento.

Comment: Não tinha conhecimento disso, mas legal show de bola, o numero 9999 era para ter uma base mesmo não para usar exatamente isso.